# Failled To Execute appendchild on Node Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Good Day,

I am busy creating a website and trying to make a gallery work. I keep getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on Node' : parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at TINY.slideshow.init

"The code snippet of the external javascript file is as follows:"
this.appendChild(g);w+=parseInt(g.offsetWidth);if(i!=this.l-1){g.style.marginRight=this.spacing+'px';w+=this.spacing}

"The script which is used within the html tags and causes the gallery slideshow to rotate is as follows:"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('slideshow').style.display='none';
 $('wrapper').style.display='block';
 var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
 window.onload=function(){
   slideshow.auto=true;
   slideshow.speed=5;
   slideshow.link="linkhover";
   slideshow.info="information";
   slideshow.thumbs="slider";
   slideshow.left="slideleft";
   slideshow.right="slideright";
   slideshow.scrollspeed=4;
   slideshow.spacing=5;
   slideshow.active="#fff";
   slideshow.init("slideshow", "image", "imgprev", "imgnext", "imglink");
 }
</script>
```

I am clueless or not well versed with Javascript but still trying to learn it. I am a Java Developer and I am trying to upskill myself with these front-end technologies like css and javascript, hence the website i am developing.
Your assistance in helping me resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
J_Diza.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error tells us that the parameter 1 (g) in appendChild() is not a node that must be it, to continue debugging I think we need that external javascript file. Try figuring out what type it is, and how you can change it.